# Changing a date format to current culture

Tags: wpf, vb.net, date, datetime, mvvm

I am trying to change a date from MM/dd/yyyy to dd/MM/yyyy, here is what I have so far:

```
        Dim d As String = value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt")
        Dim formatedDate As Date = Date.Parse(d, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
        _ArticleCreated = formatedDate
        OnPropertyChanged("ArticleCreated")
```

This works to some extent, but it will work with dates that have days 1-12. It seems to still think that the format is still MM/dd/yyyy as when I set the date to say 26/01/2016 this will look at the first column think that its a month, and error saying that this is not part of the Gregorian calender.

any suggestions?

Edit: ParseExact gives the same result

Comment: Why? Dates do not have formats, they are binary values. Formats come into play only when you want to generate a string from a date, or parse a string to a DateTime object. If you want to change how the date appears, change the [StringFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your data binding

Comment: Yeah that worked thanks, I'm only just getting into wpf and data binding, so when I did a quick search on how to do this I didn't think that it could have been done in the binding. That is why I was trying to do it in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dates do not have formats, they are binary values. Formats come into play only when you want to generate a string from a date, or parse a string to a DateTime object.

If you want to change how the date appears, change the StringFormat property of your data binding, eg:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ..., StringFormat=Date: {}{0:dd/MM/yyyy} }" />
```

An even better option though, is to ensure your application uses the proper Culture. Usually this means doing *nothing*: if eg your user's locale is set to French, the date will appear using the French format. You only need to specify which standard date format to use, eg for short date:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ..., StringFormat=d}" />
```

If you want to override the user's Culture, you can set Thread.CurrentUICulture etc.

You can also specify an explicit culture in the binding itself:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ..., StringFormat=d,  ConverterCulture=en-GB}" />
```

You aren't hard-coding the format, but you *are* hard-coding the culture.